# iOS calendar integration to app

Tags: ios, calendar

I having an app so i just added some event or remainder (football match,movie) in my app for some particular date and time.
And this add event i also want to display in iphone calendar.

thanks and regards.

Comment: [This calendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar) = win

Comment: @iosDev Even i want similar feature in my ios app, have you implemented this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: @Simon Goldeen  Eventkit looks really usefull, but i couldn't find if there is a way to actually display the calendar inside your app, can this be made with the ios framework? Or do you have to use third party api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple JTCalender for this

first oyu have to include JT Calender framework for the project

You have to create two views in your UIViewController:

The first view is JTCalendarMenuView and it represents the part with the months names. This view is optional.
The second view is JTHorizontalCalendarView or JTVerticalCalendarView, it represents the calendar itself.
Your UIViewController have to implement JTCalendarDelegate, all methods are optional.

### in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

#import "JTCalendar/JTCalendar.h"



@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,JTCalendarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)  JTCalendarMenuView *calendarMenuView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) JTHorizontalCalendarView *calendarContentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendarManager *calendarManager;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *calendarContentViewHeight;


@end


.m file
------------

#import "CalendarViewController.h"

#import "ApptWindowView.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface CalendarViewController () < UITextFieldDelegate>{
    NSMutableDictionary *dayDateDict;
    NSMutableArray*jsonDate,*dateAr1,*dateAr2;
    UITableView *appointTableView;
    CGSize screenRect;
    NSString *dateAfterString;

    int fontSize,headerBtnfont,height;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 ;
    NSString*cmpDay;
    int count;
    NSString * clickedDate;
    NSString *day ;




     NSMutableDictionary *_eventsByDate;

        NSDate *_todayDate;
        NSDate *_minDate;
        NSDate *_maxDate;

        NSDate *_dateSelected;

  UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    int i;
}




@end

@implementation CalendarViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        i=0;
    dayDateDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    dateAr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dateAr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    screenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size;





    //Create header here
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)233/255 green:(CGFloat)239/255 blue:(CGFloat)239/255 alpha:1];
    UIView * headerView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 55)];
    headerView.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:headerView];

    UILabel * titleLable =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 25, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-120, 25)];
    titleLable.text =@"CHOOSE APPOINTMENT";
    titleLable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLable.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [headerView addSubview:titleLable];

    UIButton *backButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 45, 15)];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:backButton];

    UIButton *nextButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [nextButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-60, 30, 45, 15)];
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(continueAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:nextButton];


    [self activityAction];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),^{



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // [self createUI];
            [self fetchSchedule];

            _calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
            _calendarManager.delegate = self;
            [self createMinAndMaxDate];
     _calendarContentView=[JTHorizontalCalendarView new];         
            _calendarContentView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 100,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-40 , [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-40);
            _calendarContentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

            [_calendarManager setContentView:_calendarContentView];
            [self.view addSubview:_calendarContentView];


            _calendarMenuView=[JTCalendarMenuView new];
            _calendarMenuView.frame=CGRectMake(20, 55,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-40 ,50);
            _calendarMenuView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [self.view addSubview:_calendarMenuView];
            [_calendarManager setMenuView:_calendarMenuView];
            [_calendarManager setDate:[NSDate date]];


            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });


    });

    [self createUI];

}
-(void)continueAction{
    ApptWindowView *apptWindow=[[ApptWindowView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:apptWindow animated:YES];
}
- (UIView<JTCalendarDay> *)calendarBuildDayView:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    JTCalendarDayView *view = [JTCalendarDayView new];
    view.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:13];
    view.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return view;
}




    NSError *error;   NSURLResponse * urlResponse;


    NSURL * url =[NSURL URLWithString:fetchScheduleService];

    NSMutableURLRequest  * request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:50];



    NSString * body =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"departmentId=%d",[SingletonClass sharedSingleton].deptId ];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData * data =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    if (!data) {
          [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        return;
    }
    id jsonResponse =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"schedule jason---->%@",jsonResponse);




    if ([[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"code"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:200]]) {



        jsonDate=[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"data"];


        [self convertTimeStamp];

    }
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            //[self createUI];
      //  });

//    });

}

#pragma mark-Create UI/Table View
-(void)createUI{
    appointTableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    appointTableView.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 100+screenRect.width-40+10, screenRect.width-20, screenRect.height-( 100+screenRect.width-40+10));
    appointTableView.delegate = self;
    appointTableView.dataSource = self;
    appointTableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    appointTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    appointTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:appointTableView];
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomTableViewCell * cell =(CustomTableViewCell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"calender"];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSDate * aptTime =[dateFormat1 dateFromString:[[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
    NSDate *dateAfter=[aptTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:(1800) ];
   dateAfterString =[dateFormat1 stringFromDate:dateAfter];
    NSString *dis=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",[[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],dateAfterString];





    cell.appointmentTime.text =dis;



    return  cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return  100;
    }
    return 60;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ApptWindowView *apptWindow=[[ApptWindowView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:apptWindow animated:YES];


    NSLog(@"clicked date-->%@",[[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


    NSDate * aptTime =[dateFormat1 dateFromString:[[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
    NSDate *dateAfter=[aptTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:(1800) ];
    dateAfterString =[dateFormat1 stringFromDate:dateAfter];


    NSString *dis=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ to %@ on %@",[[dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],dateAfterString,day];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dis forKey:@"appointmentTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];



}
#pragma mark-convert timeStamp to date
-(void)convertTimeStamp{




    for( NSString*valueForDate in jsonDate){



 NSTimeInterval timeSec=[valueForDate doubleValue];
 NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeSec];

 NSLog(@"\ndate are-->%@",date);

 [self separateDate:date];
    }



 }


 #pragma mark-separate date and Time
 -(void)separateDate:(NSDate*)date1{

dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


 [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

 NSString * resultTime =[dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date1];
 NSLog(@"date is-->%@",resultTime);

 [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
 NSString *resultDay=[dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date1];
 NSLog(@"day is-->%@",resultDay);



          if([cmpDay isEqual:resultDay] || cmpDay==nil){

              if(count!=1){
               [dateAr1 addObject:resultTime];
              }
              if(count==1){

                  [dateAr2 addObject:resultTime];
              }



     }
          else{

              count=1;

               dateAr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
               [dateAr2 addObject:resultTime];
          }

     cmpDay=resultDay;


     if(count!=1){
     [dayDateDict setObject:dateAr1 forKey:resultDay];
     }
     else{
     [dayDateDict setObject:dateAr2 forKey:resultDay];
     }

     NSLog(@"dictionary--->%@",dayDateDict);




 }
#pragma mark - Buttons callback

- (IBAction)didGoTodayTouch
{
    [_calendarManager setDate:_todayDate];
}

- (IBAction)didChangeModeTouch
{
    _calendarManager.settings.weekModeEnabled = !_calendarManager.settings.weekModeEnabled;
    [_calendarManager reload];

    CGFloat newHeight = 300;
    if(_calendarManager.settings.weekModeEnabled){
        newHeight = 85.;
    }

    self.calendarContentViewHeight.constant = newHeight;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate

// Exemple of implementation of prepareDayView method
// Used to customize the appearance of dayView
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    // Today
    if([_calendarManager.dateHelper date:[NSDate date] isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Selected date
    else if(_dateSelected && [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_dateSelected isTheSameDayThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = NO;
        dayView.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    // Other month
    else if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    // Another day of the current month
    else{
        dayView.circleView.hidden = YES;
        dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        dayView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    if([self haveEventForDay:dayView.date]){
        dayView.dotView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        dayView.dotView.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar didTouchDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{
    _dateSelected = dayView.date  ;

    NSLog(@"orginal Clicked day-->%@",dayView.date);



    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

            [dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];

            clickedDate =[dateFormat2 stringFromDate:_dateSelected];

            NSLog(@"Selected date===>%@",clickedDate);


            NSString* s= [dayDateDict objectForKey:clickedDate];
            NSLog(@"time is===>%@",s);

            [dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd "];

           day =[dateFormat2 stringFromDate:_dateSelected];


            NSLog(@"Selected day===>%@",day);



    // Animation for the circleView
    dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.1, 0.1);
    [UIView transitionWithView:dayView
                      duration:.3
                       options:0
                    animations:^{
                        dayView.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                        [_calendarManager reload];
                    } completion:nil];


    // Load the previous or next page if touch a day from another month

    if(![_calendarManager.dateHelper date:_calendarContentView.date isTheSameMonthThan:dayView.date]){
        if([_calendarContentView.date compare:dayView.date] == NSOrderedAscending){
            [_calendarContentView loadNextPageWithAnimation];
        }
        else{
            [_calendarContentView loadPreviousPageWithAnimation];
        }
    }

    [appointTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - CalendarManager delegate - Page mangement

// Used to limit the date for the calendar, optional
- (BOOL)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar canDisplayPageWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    return [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:date isEqualOrAfter:_minDate andEqualOrBefore:_maxDate];
}

- (void)calendarDidLoadNextPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Next page loaded");
}

- (void)calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar
{
    //    NSLog(@"Previous page loaded");
}

#pragma mark - Fake data

- (void)createMinAndMaxDate
{
    _todayDate = [NSDate date];

    // Min date will be 2 month before today
    _minDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:-3];

    // Max date will be 2 month after today
    _maxDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:3];
}


- (BOOL)haveEventForDay:(NSDate *)date
{
    if(i>=[dayDateDict allKeys].count){
        i=0;
    }
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];



    NSString *key = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];



    while(i<[dayDateDict allKeys].count){
    if([key isEqual:[[dayDateDict allKeys]objectAtIndex:i]]){
            i++;
            return YES;
    }

        else
            return NO;

    }

        return NO;






}


#pragma mark-Activity Indicator
-(void)activityAction{
    CGSize windowSize =[UIScreen  mainScreen].bounds.size;
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(windowSize.width/2-20, windowSize.height/2-55,40 ,40);
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    //[self placeSearchbaseId];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];


}


@end
```

I am fetching json data feching time form json as time stamp format and converting to local time

Then i am creating an events for it in the calender

Answer (score 0):

You have third party apps like Kal which supports calendar integration. Check this link:
[Kal Calendar](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

Hope it helps